# mongodb 3.2.11, version too new for this mongod

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have an issue with mongodb server. I am using version 3.2.11.

Unable to find metadata for table:index-3--5957523542490303670 Index: {name: *id*, ns: dashboard.dataaas} - version too new for this mongod

I have already update mongo version to 3.4, but it still could not start the server on, the error still remains.

I would like to delete that index / table, but I could not log in to mongo-shell. And could not found file index-3--5957523542490303670 in any of folder

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Basically as error states, mongo client/shell as well as mongod server should have the same version. You can check the mongo shell version using `mongo --version`. If it does not match, downgrade/upgrade client as required.
Also check if server is running.

Comment: Both server and shell return "db version v3.4.20". The server could not start because of error

Comment: okay..so your shell version is v3.4 but your db server is of 3.2.11 as stated.
now downgrade the shell to v3.2.11.
Can you show the error it's displaying.

Comment: Is there anyway to restore the DB from *.wt file? I could not use mongodump because the server is down

Comment: [some SO links for similar issues](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216759/how-to-restore-from-wt-files?noredirect=1&lq=1)
refere this. Basically you can take dump using *.wt files and then use them for restore